# VOYO Mini PC does not boot from Ubuntu Bootable USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, live-usb, bios

First of all, i have tried everything to just boot my VOYO mini PC(already had Windows 10 on it, but i formatted it), i tried disabling securing boot etc and other things but still....

Although it shows the USB in the Boot Option Priorities but when i click on the usb ...it shows a blank page with a underscore ( _ ) at the left top of the screen

I have tried everything; Ubuntu server,desktop, xubuntu, minimal version, Centos etc.

Is this something to do with the Bios?

My bios version is AM01_101D 6.20 from American Megatrends Version 2.18.1263

Please help me out as this is official work.

Please let me know for further information and clarification.

Comment: Based on your situation everything appears to look fine but have you used the rufus tool to install ubuntu portable onto a usb then boot the computer with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 17.04 running but had to jump through a few hoops.  The problem seems to be with Grub.  Creating a uefi boot partion booting syslinux and a root partition with the skeleton image included in the Ubuntu ISO by way of a little `dd if=` magic made a fully functional system that I am using to write this comment.